# Background image makes different design

Tags: html, css

html,

```
<select id="start_time" name="start_time" class="hasTimeEntry">
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
    <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
    <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
    <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
    <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
    <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
    <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
    <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
    <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
    <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
    <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
    <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
    <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
    <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
    <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
    <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
    <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
    <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option></select>
```

css,

```
#start_time {
background: url(/images/startclock_icon_small.gif) no-repeat scroll 1px 1px;
text-indent: 20px;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
width: 142px;
}
```

if i run this it shows like this,

[image]

as you can see in the pic, if i put the

```
background:url attributes
```

it shows a different design that i dont want.

i want the same design like the right textfield.

if i comment the background : url it shows fine

however, i need this img icon as a background img :(

any good idea????

========================================

**fiddle demo**
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gmu3F/)

=================================

still design that i don't want

[image]

Comment: In the DEMO it's working well, isn't it?

Comment: Works perfectly in fiddle..!

Comment: well it doesn't works in mine :( damn....

Comment: You mean to say...its not working in ur fiddle?? If it is so do an `Inspect element` in fiddle & check wt is `background` property showing. And try opening that img in a new tab.

Comment: What is wrong with your design be more clear... in your pic seems fine..

Comment: try commenting the background:url property and compare the design

Comment: You mean the border color is changing? that's all I see

Comment: @Danko she mean to say remove `background` property in ur `inspect element`

Comment: @Anup I know .... and I say the only thing I see changing is the `border color` no more

Comment: if you remove background property , then how you can see the `img`

Comment: You mean to say you want the same img i.e. of calender or do you don't want drop down arrow?

Comment: like Danko said, the border line is different

Comment: `border-color: #ccc;` add this inline style then ... if the color doesn't match, see what color is being used for the one which is you want.

Comment: @Canna: This is a problem with selects. Adding a background image will affect the default system appearance. To compensate, your can add `border: 1px solid silver; border-radius: 2px;` which will give you the same appearance.

Comment: Thanks guys, i added border-color, it is not exactcly the same, but i think the client will accept this....i hope so...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
#start_time {
   background: url(/images/startclock_icon_small.gif) no-repeat scroll 1px 1px !important;

}
```

Your `hasTimeEntry` class is overriding your `background` property.

---

Put this inline style on element which isn't working.

```
style="border-color: #ccc !important;"
```

Comment: nope not working :( and hasTimeEntry class is empty, it doesn't have any property

Comment: Clear ur cache...and then check..!

Comment: If you are using chrome try reloading the page with `ctrl+F5` to force clear cache.

Comment: nope cleared the cache, and not working. i don't think the overriding is the problem